# Setting opacity on $primary-color in sass

Tags: sass, opacity

Is there an option to include opacity on the colors you define to be your primary/secondary colors in the sass variables? In the fashion of the lighten($color, amount) function?

Comment: Did you try searching the documentation first?  http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Comment: opacify($color, 0.5)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can use `rgba`, i.e.

```
$primary: rgba(20,20,20, .5);
```

It works for hex values as well

```
$primary: rgba(#4B00B5, .3);
```

You can also set the opacity of colors based on a variable value. For example:

```
$primary-color: #a61723;
....
color: rgba($primary-color, .5);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lxDJy)

Comment: Ok thanks this is useful, but not exactly what I was looking for. Maybe I phrased my question wrong, but I'm looking for a way to add opacity to a non-opaque primary color.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "primary color", perhaps with some example code?

Comment: For example my primary color is set to: $primary-color: #a61723;

Now when I'm writing my css and I want to use it somewhere and I want it to have some opacity. Kind of like the lighten($primary-color, 10%). I'm wondering if this is possible with opacity.

Comment: You use `rgba` like I said: `color:rgba($primary-color, .5)`

Comment: @ZachSaucier that second colour is my new favourite hex code! ty

Comment: @NickGrealy You may be interested in [this tool of mine](https://codepen.io/ZachSaucier/pen/vKwVmb) that chooses the nearest "fun" hex color code :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier very nice website, sir! I see you are a man of culture... #e2071c #boobie